# Как в KivyMD обратиться к id в kv файле

Tags: python, kivy

Хочу изменить text переменной с id MainLabalId через py файл, но не знаю как до неё добраться

app.py

```
class MainApp(App):
theme_cls = ThemeManager()
title = "Application"

def build(self):
    main_widget = Builder.load_file(
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "./app.kv")
    )
    #self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Dark'

    main_widget.ids.text_field_error.bind(
        on_text_validate=self.set_error_message,
        on_focus=self.set_error_message)
    self.bottom_navigation_remove_mobile(main_widget)
    return main_widget
...
def lol(self, *args):
    self. ??? .text = 'After'
...
```

app.kv

```
NavigationLayout:
id: nav_layout
...
Screen:
            id: scr_videocard
            name: 'Videocard'
            MDLabel:
                id: MainLabalId
                font_style: 'Body1'
                theme_text_color: 'Primary'
                text: "This is the Videocard page!" #то что хочу изменить
                size_hint_x:None
                width: '250dp'
                halign: "center"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.50, "center_y": 0.75}
            MDFlatButton:
                text: 'Lol Kek'
                size_hint:    None, None
                size:        dp(50), dp(50)
                pos_hint:    {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
                on_press: app.lol()  
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спустя 4 часа поиска нашел что надо делать так:

```
def lol(self, *args):
    self.root.ids.MainLabalId.text = 'After'
```